When I run setup to create a package, how can I also automatically create pdoc documentation?
My existing setup.py creates my package fine. I added documentation with pdoc3 and want to be able to create a folder of HTML files that I can package and share. I don't see an obvious way to do this when I create the package. Any pointers please? Here's my setup.py:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

DEPENDENCIES = [
    'requests',
    'cachetools',
]

setup(
    name='common-automation-module',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='John Dwyer',
    author_email='',
    description='',
    long_description='',
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url='https://blah.com/blah',
    project_urls = {
        "Bug Tracker": "https://blah.com/utilities/blah/issues"
    },
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
    ],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
    include_package_data=True,
    scripts=[],
    python_requires=">=3.8",
    install_requires=DEPENDENCIES
)

